# Equivalent of shape-rendering="crispEdges" in PDF

Tags: pdf, svg

Consider the following SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 40 20">
  <g shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="#b4b4b4"/>
    <rect x="20" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="#b4c4b4"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The intended effect of the `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` annotation is to prevent there being a visible seam between the two rectangles, no matter how the rendering is scaled.  This works as intended when viewing the SVG file in both Firefox and Chromium.  However, when I convert the SVG into a PDF using `inkscape -A` and view the PDF, I can still see a visible seam at some zoom levels, e.g. as in this screen shot:

[image: screen shot of PDF converted from example SVG, viewed in Evince at a magnification level where there is a visible seam between the two rectangles]

Moreover, the PDF page stream produced by inkscape is identical with and without `shape-rendering="crispEdges"`

```
1 0 0 -1 0 15 cm
q
0.705882 0.705882 0.705882 rg /a0 gs
0 0 15 15 re f
0.705882 0.768627 0.705882 rg 15 0 15 15 re f
Q
```

and the `/ExtGState` dictionary referenced as `/a0` is also identical:

```
/ExtGState <<
  /a0 <<
    /CA 1
    /ca 1
  >>
>>
```

This could mean that there is no equivalent in PDF of this SVG feature, or it could mean that Inkscape's PDF exporter doesn't implement the equivalent.  I'm not having any luck finding anything that sounds like this SVG feature in [the PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), which is an argument in favor of "no equivalent", but the PDF spec is gigantic and I could easily have missed something.

So the *question* is: Is or isn't there an equivalent in PDF of this SVG feature, and if there is, how do I use it?  I am prepared to edit my exported PDF by hand if I have to.

Note 1: The example is minimal; I originally noticed the problem with a much more complicated figure from an academic paper, in which there are many such rectangles aligned to a grid, but some grid positions are empty.  I tried enlarging the rectangles in the original figure so they would overlap, and I was not able to find an amount of enlargement that eliminated all visible seams without also visibly causing the rectangles to bleed into the empty spaces.

Note 2: With the original figure, the problem is visible with Evince, pdf.js, and two printers manufactured by different companies.

Comment: There is no such feature in PDF. Though I would suggest that, from the PDF snippet, the rendering engine shouldn't be displaying a gap.

Comment: @KenS Well, arguably yes, but it _does_, and the rather more elaborate graphic that this is cut down from (also with exactly aligned rectangle edges) shows seams with two different PDF viewers and one printer.  I also tried making the rectangles slightly overlap, and could not find an amount of overlap that eliminated the seams without other visible side-effects.

Comment: All PDF viewers? Or native ones like Adobe?

Comment: Well obviously I can't comment extensively on just the short section here. I'm not saying that the PDF rendering engines don't sdhow a gap, just that they shouldn't. From what's presented an overlap also should not be visible, and if it is then again I'd say that's a bug in the rendering engine. I presume you are using pdf.js to view the PDF files in a web broweser ? That's notoriously poor at rendering, though usually its transparency it fails to get right. Simple stuff is usually OK. And the fact remains, there's no way to define two objects in PDF as being precisely aligned.

Comment: Both rectangles are solid colour. So have you considered eliminating the problem by just extending the grey rectangle rightwards so that the green rectangle overlaps it?  https://jsfiddle.net/x0hftnr5/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Tried that, couldn't find an expansion factor that eliminated the problem without undesirable side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in PDF would be to use shading meshes (e.g. tensor and lattice free form meshes). This will remove the slivers in most viewers.

Some PDF viewers ( like Acrobat, Xodo/PDFTron) have options that minimize the appearance of these slivers, but generally it's not well implemented across many implementations.